# android обрезка видео

Tags: android, видео, android-camera

Записал видео благодаря Camera2 Api и сохранил в галерею. Теперь мне нужно это видео каждые допустим 1 секунд обрезать преобразовывая в фото.
Знаю что мудрено звучит, но мало ли кто то знает.Буду вам очень благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: можно ffmpeg'ом можно mplayr'ом

Comment: я имею ввиду чтобы это все происходило в приложении